# How to store an ArrayList from Java code in MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, database-design

which is a better approach

**a)** Store AL as BLOB
**b)** Create columns to store each of the string that makes the AL.

Is there any other approach that I can take?

Comment: Why create columns and not simply rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Avoid Serializing objects.

There are huge potential traps when it comes to serializing objects.
Joshua Bloch has a complete section in [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) , dedicated to Serialization where he concludes that you should avoid it if possible.

So go for option **B**

Answer (score 6):

Ofcourse **b**

```
class Person{
  String name;
  int age;
  //getters setters and other stuff
}

List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

---

Table

```
PERSON_MASTER
```

`id  |  name |   age`

**Also See**

- [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)
- [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/docs)

Answer (score 2):

You should go with the approach **b**, because:

- In a future version of Java, the structure of the `ArrayList` class may change and thus you won't be able to deserialize the BLOBs back to `ArrayList` instances
- In the future, you might want to use the same database with a language other than Java (e.g. C# in .NET) you can't simply deserialize the `ArrayList` BLOBs back to .NET lists.
- When you store the `ArrayList` as the BLOB, and go to your DBMS management console, and write queries, you won't be able to see the contents of those BLOBs.

Having said that I recommend you to read an introductory book about SQL and database design as well as a theoretical book about relational algebra. This will make things much clearer to you.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a table to store your list of values.

Table A : idA, col1, col2

Table B : idB, ida, rank, value

With of course a foreignkey on ida in table B

Answer (score 0):

I'd say approach B. Storing the entire list in a single blob removes a lot of advantages of using a database in the first place.

If it's a list of complex objects, look at something like JPA or Hibernate to assist you with the database interactions.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a quick course in DB modelling... you are refering here to a 1:N relationship, this is used storing each String as a row in a different table, with a foreign key (a reference) to the row in the original table where your object is.